# Functor in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How can I create functor in TypeScript?

EDIT:

Functor is, in C++ world, function that can hold state - basically class that has overriden `()` operator.

So, for example, I'm able to do following:

```
class myClass {
    var value : string;
    // how?
    functor() : string {
        return value;
    }
}



var a = new myClass();
a.value = "abc";
a(); // to return "abc"
```

Comment: Added to tips : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/statefulFunctions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So really what you have here is a method on a class, like this:

```
class myClass {
    constructor(private text: string) {

    }

    methodName() : string {
         return this.text;
    }
}

var a = new myClass('Example');
a.methodName(); // 'Example'
```

If you just want a plain function, you can do that too:

```
function functor(text : string) : string {
     return "abc";
}

functor('text');
```

## Difference Between JS-Style Functor and Class Output

You can attempt to reproduce a functor, like this:

```
function functor(text : string) : () => string {
     return function() {
         return text;
     }
}

var x = functor('Example');
x(); // returns 'Example'
```

But actually, using a class gives you the very similar:

```
var myClass = (function () {
    function myClass(text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    myClass.prototype.methodName = function () {
        return this.text;
    };
    return myClass;
})();
var a = new myClass('Example');
a.methodName(); // 'Example'
```

With the benefits of class semantics... you can extend the class, you can generate an interface from the class and so on.

Comment: Updated the question. I need to have function that is able to keep some state.

Comment: A class is a great place to store state in TypeScript. You can, if you like, also write it long hand in JavaScript, but if you look at the compiled class you'll see that it is a very similar concept.

Comment: @Yossarian, in plain js you can add to function property, so any function can save some state

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript / JavaScript doesn't work that way, but you can get something close.

```
function makeFunctor(privateText: string) {
    return function (text: string): string {
        return privateText + text;
    };
}

var a = makeFunctor('abc');
var b = a('def');

// Logs "abcdef"
console.log(b);
```

Comment: This is quite similar to the kind of code you get from using a class in TypeScript, so it is questionable whether there is benefit in doing it long-hand.

Comment: Yup, I agree, I don't actually use this pattern.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a function that holds state, recommend using a namespace with a non exported variable:

```
namespace c {
    let str = "private";
    export function func(text: string = str) {
        str = text;
        return text;
    }
}

console.log(c.func()); // private
console.log(c.func('new')); // new
console.log(c.func()); // new
```

More on namespaces : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/namespaces.html

Answer (score -1):

It's sort of unclear what you are asking for exactly, but in your sample code, the keyword `function` is not needed in TypeScript, and also `functor` is a method on the instance of your class, which is `a` so you would call it with `a.functor('text');`

This code works:

```
class myClass {
    // how?
    functor(text : string) : string {
    // /how?
         return "abc";
    }
}

var a = new myClass();
a.functor('text'); // to return "abc"
```

---

[This link (Functional JavaScript - Functors)](http://functionaljavascript.blogspot.com/2013/07/functors.html) may also help explain implementations of functors in JavaScript (if you write it in JS first, it shouldn't be hard to translate to TS)

Comment: Your example isn't a functor, it is a method named `functor`. C++ has nice functors, I suggest check it.

Comment: My code here is the OP's code. My answer was written before the OP edited his question to better explain what he was after.

Answer (score -1):

Any old `function` can have state.

```
class MyClass {
  var state = 0;
  function addstate(value: number) {
    state += value;
    return state;
  }
}

var stateholder = new MyClass();

stateholder.addstate(3); //3
stateholder.addstate(3); //6
```

Comment: It is not a functor, it is a class with a method.

Comment: C++ does this with an operator method named `operator()`. In the case of the ts, I think some default export - trickery would follow best the logic of the language.

Comment: @peterh ts doesn't define "functor", so what is and isn't a functor isn't defined. According to the definition "a function that has state", when you don't want to call something after a `.` a function, something like http://pastebin.com/XqnjH85J may be what you want. I'm not a stickler for terminology, feel free to call s in that example a functor (I don't know when the above solution stopped working, but it doesn't work anymore)

Comment: @peterh the C++ spec doesn't include any definition of "functor" either.