# Does Typescript support functors?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface T { a: A }, and I would like to lift it to TS { a: S }, is there a way to write something like a functor to do this in Typescript?

I know this won't actually generate any runtime code, this is mostly just to make writing types at compile time less tedious.

Comment: This might help   http://stackoverflow.com/a/32970360/1702612

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example with full code?